# How to use BulkCopy without Defining the Destination Table

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

All,

I have the following `BulkCopy` operation:

```
// Convert the FlexGrid to a DataTable.
DataTable currData = (DataTable)c1ErrFlexGrid.DataSource;

// Insert the data into the database.
SqlBulkCopy SqlBulkIns = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default);
SqlBulkIns.BatchSize = 5000;
SqlBulkIns.DestinationTableName = String.Format("dbo.{0}", strTableName);
SqlBulkIns.WriteToServer(currData);
```

where `strConnectionString` is a defined and valid connection string. This has worked fine in the past when the table `strTableName` exists and the fields are defined. I now wish to perform this `BulkCopy` operation on a `DataTable` that is defined at run-time; that is, without predefining the table structure in SQL. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a table and bulk load the data into it from the datatable? (i.e. the table does not exist in sql server)?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to ask the user for a table name and your program will actually create a table with the same schema as `c1ErrFlexGrid.DataSource` and then populate it?

Comment: Yes you are both right... If the table exists in SQL Server the above code works. I want to know how to bulk load the `DataTable` into SQL Server when the table does not currently exist, without pre-defining it.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this except to manually create the table in advance (based on your datatable schema).  You would need some code that checks if table exists and creates it if not.

Comment: I was worried someone would say that! Thanks for your time. If you make this an answer I will gladly accept...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this [SqlTableCreator](http://darrylagostinelli.com/2011/06/27/create-a-sql-table-from-a-datatable-in-c-net/) object to create a SQL table from your datatable and then run the bulk insert.

Comment: Nice library! Was going to suggest (basically) coding that. +1 for lazy.

Comment: +1 This is actually what I ended up doing. 5 days too late, but a great find! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if the DBF file changes constantly? I want to create the table on the fly before writing to it.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Is there any mirror available?

Comment: Maybe this link can serve as a new class; I did not have a chance to see the above-mentioned class before, so I'm merely posting what I found to be useful:
http://code.google.com/p/besasm-legacy/source/browse/DotNet/SQLUtils/DatabaseManagement/SQLHelper/SQLTableCreator.cs